# Problem implementing a method outside of a header file

Tags: c++, struct

I declared a method for this struct:

```
struct Foo {
    int bar;
    void foo_bar();
}
```

But when I implement it in my regular cpp file it gives me an error:

```
void foo_bar() {
    cout << "Foobar" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you have to tell the compiler that the function you're implementing is the one that's a member of that struct/class, rather than a free function with (otherwise) the same name.

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int bar;
    void foo_bar();
};

void Foo::foo_bar() {
    cout << "Foobar" << endl;
}
```

It's perfectly legitimate<sup>1</sup>, however, to have `Foo::foo_bar` and `::foo_bar` defined in the same file, (and if you wanted to, you could also define a class `Bar` that also contained a `foo_bar()`) so the compiler won't try to guess that this `foo_bar` is really supposed to be `Foo::foo_bar`, `::foo_bar` or `Bar::foo_bar`.

---

1. At least legitimate as far as the compiler cares. Many style guides might disagree.

Comment: Do I have to redeclare the struct in my cpp file if I wrote this in my header file, or I can just directly write Foo::foo_bar implementation

Comment: Generally, you'll `#include` the header in its corresponding cpp file, which automatically declares all of the relevant structures.

Comment: It is *necessary* for struct/class `Foo` to be defined (in a way visible to the compiler) and for that struct/class definition to declare the member function `foo_bar()` before defining `F::foo_bar()` outside that struct/class.